# Add more rows on media picker

Tags: customization, media-library

I'm trying to add more rows in the media picker modal window. Is there any clean way to achieve doing this ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can upload multiple files by ctrl+click. Does that resolve your issue?

Comment: Thanks but it's not the point ;)
I want to be able to visualize more than 10 uploaded images by page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mediapicker-more-rows/

**I found a way to fix the pagination**

There is a way you can 'hook' into paginate_links. There is no official hook for it, but you can change the $wp_query->found_posts variable.

What I did here is 'hooking' into the paginate_links by abusing the media_upload_mime_type_links filter and setting a new value for $wp_query->found_posts.

This filter is triggered just before paginate_links is called.

```
function set_paginate_limit_mediapicker( $type_links )
{   
    global $wp_query;       

    $new_limit = 30; // set your limit
    $wp_query->found_posts = $wp_query->found_posts / ( $new_limit / 10 );

    return $type_links; // not used 
}   
add_filter( 'media_upload_mime_type_links', 'set_paginate_limit_mediapicker', 1 );
```

I have made a WordPress plugin for the complete solution, which you will find in the repository.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mediapicker-more-rows/

Comment: Amazing, tschutter! Pity is that I did put a bounty of 100 points on this question that ended some days ago...

Comment: That's ok, glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

This works but the big issue is to solve the pagination, because it is completely broken.

```
add_filter('post_limits','wpse_33775_add_rows_to_media_library',999,1);

function wpse_33775_add_rows_to_media_library($limits)
{   
    global $current_screen;
    $tab = isset( $_GET['tab'] ) ? $_GET['tab'] : "type";

    if( 'media-upload' != $current_screen->id && 'library' != $tab )
        return $limits;

    $my_new_limit = '100';
    $limits = str_replace('10',$my_new_limit,$limits); // replacing the default 10

    return $limits;
}
```

---

Is there a way to hook here?

```
/*
 * WordPress 3.3.2
 * /wp-admin/includes/media.php
 * line 1828
 *
 */   
$page_links = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
    'format' => '',
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'total' => ceil($wp_query->found_posts / 10),
    'current' => $_GET['paged']
));

if ( $page_links )
    echo "<div class='tablenav-pages'>$page_links</div>";
```